# RecyclerView not working properly: adapter isnt attaching

Tags: java, android, json, android-recyclerview

There's something wrong with my adapater class. I've tried so many times to figure out why the adapter isnt attaching to the recycler. keeps skipping layout please help :S. I don't know any coders experienced using Recyclers. im unsure where im messing up here. no line of code shows any errors either. but i have two methods that are greyed out.

> Adapter class

```
public Adapter(Context context,List<Articles> articles) {
    this.context = context;
    this.articles = articles;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent,false);

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}`

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final Articles a=articles.get(position);
    String url = a.getUrl();
    holder.tvTitle.setText(a.getTitle());

    holder.tvSource.setText(a.getSource().getName());
    holder.tvDate.setText(a.getPublishedAt());


    String imageUrl=a.getUrlToImage();

    Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).into(holder.imageView);
    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(context, NewsInDetails.class);
            intent.putExtra("url",a.getUrl());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return articles.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView tvTitle,tvSource,tvDate;
    ImageView imageView;
    CardView cardView;
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tvTitle=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvId);
        tvDate=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
        tvSource=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSource);
        imageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        cardView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
    }}
public String getCountry()
{
    Locale locale=Locale.getDefault();
    String country=locale.getCountry();
    return country.toLowerCase();    }}
```

> main class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView recyclerView;
Adapter adapter;
final String apiKey = "732e904090094f96be1cd5f012f107a3";
Button button;
ImageButton floatingActionButton;
List<Articles> articles =new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView =findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    button=findViewById(R.id.refreshButton);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    final String country=getCountry();

    floatingActionButton=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.floating);
    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Intro.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    retrieveGSON(country,apiKey);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            retrieveGSON(country,apiKey);
        }
    });
}
public  void retrieveGSON(String country, String apiKey)
{
    Call<Headlines> call= Client.getInstance().getApi().getHeadlines(country, apiKey);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Headlines>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Headlines> call, Response<Headlines> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body().getArticles()!=null)
            {
                articles.clear();
                articles = response.body().getArticles();

                adapter = new Adapter(MainActivity.this, articles);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Headlines> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"There is An Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}}
```

Comment: if they are greyed out it means they aren't being used anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Set Adapter to recyclerview in onCreate() then

ex:
`adapter = new Adapter(MainActivity.this, articles); recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);`

In onResponse update the  articles latest data to the adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged() on adapter

ex:

```
  public setData(List<Articles> articles){
  this.articles = articles
   notifyDataSetChanged}
  }
```

Comment: hey thanks for the help! that didnt work for me unfortunately. My app went blank instead :s

Comment: are you getting success response data in onResponse for articles, check with logs.

Comment: [FATAL:jni_android.cc(243)]  is the error in the logcat

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no wrong with the coding but just notify the adapter as
adapter.notifyDatasetChanged().
Also check whether you are passing correct ID's for the views( Fatal Error).